# Talent show program in C#

Tags: c#

I need some help with this program I got from a programming website, I am still new to programming and this seems like too much for me right now. I don't even know where to begin with this program:

In one of the last problems, you created the most recent version of the GreenvilleRevenue program, which prompts the user for contestant data for this year’s Greenville Idol competition. Now, save all the entered data to a Greenville.ser file(this is provided by the website) that is closed when data entry is complete and then reopened and read in, allowing the user to view lists of contestants with requested talent types. The program should output the name of the contestant, the talent, and the fee.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
class GreenvilleRevenue
{
   static void Main()
{
  const int MIN_CONTESTANTS = 0;
  const int MAX_CONTESTANTS = 30;
  int num;
  int revenue = 0;
  const char QUIT = 'Z';
  char option = ' ';;
  Contestant[] contestants = new Contestant[MAX_CONTESTANTS];
  num = getContestantNumber(MIN_CONTESTANTS, MAX_CONTESTANTS);
  revenue = getContestantData(num, contestants, revenue); 
  WriteLine("\n\nRevenue expected this year is {0}", revenue.ToString("C"));
  while(option != QUIT)
     option = getLists(num, contestants);     
}
private static int getContestantNumber(int min, int max)
{
  string entryString;
  int num  = max + 1;
  Write("Enter number of contestants >> ");
  entryString = ReadLine();
  while(num < min || num > max)
  {
     if(!int.TryParse(entryString, out num))
     {
         WriteLine("Format invalid");
         num = max + 1;
         Write("Enter number of contestants >> ");
         entryString = ReadLine();
     }
     else
     {
        try
        {
           if(num < min || num > max)
              throw(new ArgumentException());
        }
        catch(ArgumentException e)
        {
           WriteLine(e.Message);
           WriteLine("Number must be between {0} and {1}", min, max);
           num = max + 1;
           Write("Enter number of contestants >> ");
           entryString = ReadLine();
        }
     }
  }
  return num;
}
private static int getContestantData(int num, Contestant[] contestants, int revenue)
{
  const int ADULTAGE = 17;
  const int TEENAGE = 12;
  int x = 0;
  string name;
  char talent;
  int age;
  int pos;
  while(x < num)
  {
     Write("Enter contestant name >> ");
     name = ReadLine();
     WriteLine("Talent codes are:");
     for(int y = 0; y < Contestant.talentCodes.Length; ++y)
        WriteLine("  {0}   {1}", Contestant.talentCodes[y], Contestant.talentStrings[y]);
     Write("       Enter talent code >> ");
     char.TryParse(ReadLine(), out talent);
     try
     {
        validateCode(talent, out pos);
     }
     catch(ArgumentException e)
     {
        WriteLine(e.Message);
        WriteLine("{0} is not a valid code. Assigned as Invalid.", talent);
     }
      Write("       Enter contestant's age >> ");
     int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out age);
     if(age > ADULTAGE)
        contestants[x] = new AdultContestant();
     else
        if(age > TEENAGE)
           contestants[x] = new TeenContestant();
        else
           contestants[x] = new ChildContestant();
     contestants[x].Name = name;
     contestants[x].TalentCode = talent;
     revenue += contestants[x].Fee;
     ++x;
  }
  return revenue;
}
 private static char getLists(int num, Contestant[] contestants)
 {
  int x;
  char QUIT = 'Z';
  char option = ' ';
  bool isValid;
  int pos = 0;
  bool found;
  WriteLine("\nThe types of talent are:");
  for(x = 0; x < Contestant.talentStrings.Length; ++x)
     WriteLine("{0, -6}{1, -20}", Contestant.talentCodes[x], Contestant.talentStrings[x]);
  Write("\nEnter a talent type or {0} to quit >> ", QUIT);
  isValid = false;
  while(!isValid)
  {
     if(!char.TryParse(ReadLine(), out option))
     {
        isValid = false;

        WriteLine("Invalid format - entry must be a single character");
        Write("\nEnter a talent type or {0} to quit >> ", QUIT);  
     }
     else
     {
        if(option == QUIT)
           isValid = true;
        else
        {
           try
           {
              validateCode(option, out pos);
              isValid = true;
           }
           catch(ArgumentException e)
           {
               WriteLine(e.Message);
               WriteLine("{0} is not a valid code", option);
               Write("\nEnter a talent type or {0} to quit >> ", QUIT);
               isValid = false;
           }
        }
        if(isValid && option != QUIT)
        {

            WriteLine("\nContestants with talent {0} are:", Contestant.talentStrings[pos]);
            found = false;
            for(x = 0; x < num; ++x)
            {
                if(contestants[x].TalentCode == option)
                {
                    WriteLine(contestants[x].ToString());
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if(!found)
            {
                 WriteLine("No contestants had talent {0}", Contestant.talentStrings[pos]);
              isValid = false;
              Write("\nEnter a talent type or {0} to quit >> ", QUIT);
           }
        }
     }
  }
   return option;
  }
  public static void validateCode(char option, out int pos)
  {
  bool isValid = false;
  pos = Contestant.talentCodes.Length - 1;
  for(int z = 0; z < Contestant.talentCodes.Length; ++z)
  {
     if(option == Contestant.talentCodes[z])
     {
        isValid = true;
        pos = z;
     }
  }
  if(!isValid)
     throw(new ArgumentException()); 
 }
}

class Contestant
{
 public static char[] talentCodes = {'S', 'D', 'M', 'O'};    
 public static string[] talentStrings = {"Singing", "Dancing",
       "Musical instrument", "Other"};
 public string Name {get; set;}
 private char talentCode;
 private string talent;
 private int fee;
 public char TalentCode
{
  get
  {
     return talentCode;
  }
  set
  {
     int pos = talentCodes.Length;
     for(int x = 0; x < talentCodes.Length; ++x)
        if(value == talentCodes[x])
           pos = x;
     if(pos == talentCodes.Length)
     {
        talentCode = 'I';
        talent = "Invalid";
     }
     else
     {
        talentCode = value;
        talent = talentStrings[pos];
     }
  }   

}
public string Talent
{
   get
   {
      return talent;
   }
}
public int Fee
{
  get
  {
     return fee;
  }
  set
  {
     fee = value;
  }
 }
}
class AdultContestant : Contestant
{
 public int ADULT_FEE = 30;
 public AdultContestant()
 {
  Fee = ADULT_FEE;
}
public override string ToString()
{
  return("Adult Contestant " + Name + " " + TalentCode + "   Fee " + Fee.ToString("C"));
} 
}   
class TeenContestant : Contestant
{
 public int TEEN_FEE = 20;
 public TeenContestant()
   {
   Fee = TEEN_FEE;
   }
   public override string ToString()
  {
   return("Teen Contestant " + Name + " " + TalentCode + "   Fee " + Fee.ToString("C"));
 } 
} 
class ChildContestant : Contestant
{
 public int CHILD_FEE = 15;
 public ChildContestant()
 {
  Fee = CHILD_FEE;
 }
 public override string ToString()
 {
   return("Child Contestant " + Name + " " + TalentCode + "   Fee " + Fee.ToString("C"));
 } 
}
```

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately, 'Can anyone help me?' is not really the sort of problem that Stack Overflow is designed for. It's for at-least-fairly-specific questions, not for discussions (and talking through designing and implementing a program from scratch would definitely require a discussion). It would be much more helpful (and more likely to get answered) if you described the efforts you've taken on your own to answer the question and the more specific problems you've run into in the process.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and advice, sadly I was afraid that having such a long program would be a problem but I did not know where else to ask for help. If you or anyone else might know a more appropriate place please let me know. As for the title, I was not sure what to say since there is so much going on in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Mark's opinion, as well as the others who have up-voted his comment.
I wouldn't wait on someone to post a solution to your question so I'll go ahead and give you some things to get started on your own research and solution.

(Most of this is already in your problem statement, just broken down)

1. Start with the existing code you've pasted in
2. Read it line by line and google/textbook/stackoverflow ANYTHING you don't understand. Get a general understanding, and go deep if you have time.
3. Learn how to save data to a file in C#
4. Learn how to load data from a file in C#
5. Find a place in the code for the save data logic. (after data entry)
6. Run load data logic after save data logic
7. Display what was loaded

Edit: As you do research, you'll find lots of stackoverflow posts with good answers. Follow the format for those questions *(prior research, attempted solutions, specific question, small code snippets)* in order to ask more engaging questions yourself.